# mySQL Mac Terminal Error Logging In (getting a picture of a key)

Tags: mysql, macos

When logging into mySQL on my terminal (MAC) and when I enter cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/; ls -> ./mysql -u root it shows "Password: and then a picture of a key" and doesn't let me input my password. Anyone know how to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can input your password perfectly fine. Type the password and press enter. The command line interface on MacOS (and most other command lines) do not display stars (*) when typing a password (as you might expect) and instead it appears that you are typing nothing.

Comment: Worth mentioning is _why_ this happens: it's an extra security feature which prevents shoulder surfers from seeing how long your password is.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah it works now! Probably a dumb question but I appreciate the feedback! :)